# BASH/Linux - Finding the next date from a variable

Tags: linux, bash, date, variables

In my Unix shell programming, I am trying to get the next date (tomorrow's date) over a reference date defined as "a". Here is the code:

```
a=2016-01-02
```

Which operator would I use in my code so that Unix will automatically define a as tomorrow's date as in below

```
a=2016-01-03
```

Comment: Are you using date under `FreeBSD` or `GNU`? Can you output `date --version`

Answer (score 2):

`date` has a `-d` option that is very useful in this situation.

To get the next day, add a space after the date then add `1 day`

```
date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$a 1 day"
```

It's important to add the format specifier because without it, you would get the following output

```
=>"Sun Jan 3 00:00:00  UTC 2016"
```

To update the `a` variable, you could do something like this

`a=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$a 1 day")`

Remember to wrap the command inside of parentheses with a `$` sign in front of it.